# In Laravel, how can i return a specific *column* from a *table* inside my API Controller ? I'm using Laravel 5

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

**Question**

How can i return a specific *column* from a *table* [within the API Controller] ? I used **pluck** but it removed the column name from the output. I need the column name to be included as well. The $product table i refer(Referred in my code below) is just a  table with product stuffs like name, price, discount rate etc..

**Brief description**

Present API response sample -

```
{
   "data" : [
      "Graham",
      "Marina Philip",
      "David Doomer",
           ],
   "message" : "",
   "success" : true
}
```

**Expected response -**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Graham",
  },
  {
    "name": "Marina Philip",
  },  {
    "name": "David Doomer",
  },

]
```

**API Route from the APIController :**

```
Route::resource('searchlist', 'API\SearchlistAPIController');
```

**Index function from my SearchlistAPIController.php  [Specific function]**

```
           public function index(Request $request)
            {
                try{
                    $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new RequestCriteria($request));
                    $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new LimitOffsetCriteria($request));
                    $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new ProductsOfFieldsCriteria($request));
                    if($request->get('trending',null) == 'week'){
                        $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new TrendingWeekCriteria($request));
                    }
                    else{
                        $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new NearCriteria($request));
                    }

                    $products = $this->productRepository->all();
        
                } catch (RepositoryException $e) {
                    return $this->sendError($e->getMessage());
                }
    //Here i've got the value of the table $Product with a bunch of columns from my database..
        
                $sendinger = $products->pluck('name');    
 
   //I'm trying to filter the columns send here. But i lost the column name as well.            
                
               return $this->sendResponse($sendinger->toArray(),'');
            }
```

Contents of my `sendResponse` method:

`public function sendResponse($result, $message) { return Response::json(ResponseUtil::makeResponse($message, $result)); }`

Also, how can i remove this from my Json response ? :

```
 "message" : "",
   "success" : true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I believe `$products->pluck('name')->toArray()` will create return an indexed array. E.g. `[ "Graham", "Marina Philip", "David Doomer" ]`

What you could do is...

```php
$sendinger = $products->pluck('name')->map(function($name) {
    return [ 'name' => $name ];
});
                
return $this->sendResponse($sendinger->toArray(),'');
```

More about mapping here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-map

Not tested but should steer you in the right direction.

---

For your other question (removing "success" and "message" from the response)...

It appears you are using the [Laravel Generator](https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator/) `ResponseUtil` class which is adding the additional parameters. See source here: https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator/blob/7.0/src/Utils/ResponseUtil.php

Simply replace the last line:

```
return $this->sendResponse($sendinger->toArray(),'');
```

with

```
return response()->json( $sendinger->toArray() );
```

and that should do the trick!

Comment: Thank you for your help @Levi Cole. Your suggestion Indeed added the field name. A bit more help 

How can I remove the curly braces & remove the **data** from this response ?

{
   "data" : [
           {
         "name" : "Graham"
            },
            {
         "name" : "David Woober"
            },
    ]
}

& change the JSON response  something like this : 


[
           {
         "name" : "Graham"
            },

            {
         "name" : "David Woober"
            },
    
]


I'm accepting this as the answer for your quick help

Comment: @AdrianKarr I believe the response output is controlled by the `sendResponse` method. If you can add the contents of that method to your question I can maybe help.

Comment: sure thing. I just updated my post to include the sendResponse method in the end. Could you please take a look ? Thank you again for your time

Comment: Thank you so much man! Your suggestion did the trick & you've been a fantastic help this day!